# How can I record from YouTube videos or Streaming videos in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: software-installation

How can I record from YouTube videos or Streaming videos in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?
I wish to record the "Ring of Fire" solar eclipse event, and also others from online - whether streaming live or just a video.

Comment: hi @gwgeorge007 You can use yt-dlp to download both regular and live-streaming videos: `https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp`. Installation: `https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/wiki/Installation`. Usage: `https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#usage-and-options`. Example: `yt-dlp -f '312+234' --merge-output-format mp4 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LlY79zjud-Q --live-from-start is_live`.

Comment: `yt-dlp` GitHub repo have detailed 3 installation options for Linux. I have installed it using: `sudo wget https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp -O /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp` then `sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/yt-dlp`.

Comment: probably not for live streaming, but this one works well in Firefox. https://en.loader.to/4/ where youtube-dl and yt-dlp have failed (youtubes) . yt-dlp as a 'sh yt-dlp' command line sometimes works.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a GTK3 application, where you simply drag and drop a video unto the UI and process it.
[image: 1]
It uses Yt-dlp as engine, with the focus on best video and audio quality. Therefore, FFmpeg will be a prerequisite.

Documented [here,](https://github.com/kanehekili/YoutubeDownloader) you can install (and trust) my ppa:

Add the ppa and install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jentiger-moratai/mediatools
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ytdownloader
```

Questions and issues on github

Answer (score 0):

Install **video downloadhelper** in Firefox.

In Firefox, Click on "**Tools**" then select "**Add-ons and Themes**"

Type in "video downloadhelper" in the search box.

Select video downloadhelper and click on "**Add to Firefox**" to install.

Instructions on how to use this Add-on can be found on the page in the previous step which is also [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search)

Comment: I removed Firefox and replaced it with [Librewolf](https://librewolf.net/) which suits all my needs. With Librewolf, any downloadable you tube video I watch with a front end called [Invidious](https://invidious.io) has in the right click context menu the possibility of saving to disk. No tracking and no ads.